# Kentico Configuration and Database Scripting

Tags: c#, scripting, content-management-system, kentico

I've just started working with Kentico as a CMS and I am looking at configuration and set-up of Kentico on a fresh PC (or pulling down a repo to a new PC).

I just looking around to see if there was the ability to Script the configuration of Kentico and it's Database, for example the creation of Page Templates (and their reference to .aspx files) or the creation of Pages/Menu structure themselves.

Is there any scripting interface for this type of thing, or am I stuck using the Administrator pages and storing the database in source control?

Comment: Did you read the installation guide and its documentation?

Answer (score 0):

There is an API available to do the things in code. I am not aware of SQL scripts since they could be really complicated to ensure all the constraints and relation ships. The [API examples](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/API+examples) are available within the project files folder.

Comment: I'll check the API, I really hope they have an API to interact with Portal functionality, than than using the UI. Going through the Portal doesn't seem like a good idea for source control reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to store Kentico objects as files in the files system while still working with the Portal Engine, then you can do so by going to CMSSiteManager > Administration > System > Virtual Objects and then configure the options under Source Control (this is the location in Kentico Version 7, I'm not sure where it is in Version 8).

Check out this article in Kentico's docs:

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Deployment+mode+for+virtual+objects